# How to query ElasticSearch using regular expressions?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm reading the [Reqexp Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) for ElasticSearch but somehow it doesn't work for me.

I'd like to find any product that contains "card". My query is something like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "regexp":{
            "product": "*card*"
        }
    }
}
```

I get zero hits. Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `.` in the regular expression.

This should work:

```
{
    "query": {
        "regexp":{
            "product": ".*card.*"
        }
    }
}
```